# Get rid of error message box during StartService action

Tags: windows-installer

I need to try to stop some windows service during installation of my product and try to run after. The service is not related with the product, it may or may not exist on a certain PC. It may or may not run at the moment of product (de)installation. I don't care if service stop/run was successful or not, for example it's fine if the service fails to run after the installation complete.

I added `ServiceControl` table in my msi-package, i set `Wait` option `0`.
In the case the service is not installed on the system, i get an error MessageBox

[image: Error message box]

Besides `/passive`|`/quiete` installation option or using `CustomAction`, are there ways to get rid of this MessageBox? I just don't want it to appear.

I don't use WiX.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that error can be suppressed when using the ServiceControl table, but another option is to use Custom Actions:

You could use two type 34 custom actions instead (one to stop, one to start).

- Set the Working directory to be SystemFolder.
- Set the command line to be: NET [START|STOP] [ServiceName].
- Set the return processing to be synchronous and to ignore the exit code.
- Set the in script execution option to be 'Deferred in a System Context'.
- Schedule the start/stop (you will need 2) custom actions between InstallInitialise and InstallFinalise.

Your custom action table will ultimately look similar to this:

```
Action              Type    Source          Target
NewCustomAction1    3170    SystemFolder    NET STOP ServiceName
NewCustomAction2    3170    SystemFolder    NET START ServiceName
```

and your InstallExecuteSequence similar to this:

```
Action              Condition       Sequence
NewCustomAction1    NOT Installed   1501
NewCustomAction2    NOT Installed   6599
```

Comment: It seems the CustmoAction is the only solution. What 3170 is for?

Comment: 3170 is just an accumulation of flag bits in decimal format. I'm just on my mobile at the moment but have a read of this: https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpDLLFunctionCalcType.htm

Comment: I think that should amount to: *"Launch executable from directory"*, *"Run deferred"* (when system changes are applied - as opposed to immediate: when system changes are being scheduled AND when they are being done), *"Run as localsystem - no impersonation"*, *"Wait for custom action to finish before proceeding"*.